# General Formula for Sum of Increasing Ratios

Tags: summation, continued-fractions, ratio

What is the general formula, if any, for the following sum of increasing ratios?

$$
\frac{i}{c}+\frac{a}{c(1-x)}+\frac{ab}{c(1-2x)}+\frac{ab^2}{c(1-3x)}+\cdots+\frac{ab^n}{c(1-(n+1)x)}
$$

Each subsequent numerator with $a$ is the previous one multiplied by a factor $b$; ie, for a factor of 1.5 the sequence would be $50, 75, 112.5,\ldots$

$i$ is just an arbitrary numerator for the first fraction. All the numerators can be added together involving a geometric sum:

$$i+a \Bigl(\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b-1}\Bigr)$$

Each subsequent denominator is $c$ reduced in steps of $x$ percent in decimal form. For example, if $c$ is 555 in the first fraction and $x$ is 0.04 the following denominators would be 532.8, 510.6, 488.4... All denominators summed up contain the sum of all natural numbers up to $n+1$:

$$c\Bigl[n+2-x\Bigl(\frac{n^2+3n+2}{2}\Bigr)\Bigr]$$

But we know that
$\frac{m+p}{n+q} \ne \frac{m}{n}+\frac{p}{q}$. Yet, since there are formulas for the sum of the numerators and the denominators, -as shown- there might be one to express their ratio.

Comment: Question is strange!  Sum of increasing terms becomes infinite!

Comment: @herbsteinberg Since there are formulas for the sum of the numerators and denominators I suspect that it might be possible to assemble one for the increasing ratios as well.

Comment: I don't know if there is a closed form for what you want, but having a closed form for the denominators and numerators sums is not a decisive factor. We have those for the partials sums of the harmonic series as well, and there isn't a nice closed form. Look up the Wikipedia article "Harmonic number", for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, you made quite strange (and wrong) manipulations.

Hoping that you enjoy special functions
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a b^k}{c (1-(k+1) x)}=\frac a c\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{ b^k}{ 1-(k+1) x}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{ b^k}{ 1-(k+1) x}=\frac1 x \Bigg[b^{n+1} \Phi \left(b,1,n+2-\frac{1}{x}\right)-\Phi
   \left(b,1,1-\frac{1}{x}\right) \Bigg]$$ where appear  the [Lerch transcendent function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).

Comment: Please point to my mistakes. Are they in the algebra or the interpretation of my own operations?